# Installing SSL Certificate on AWS EBS Single Instance (Tomcat)

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

During the process of installation of SSL certificate (obtained from CA) on my AWS EBS Single Instance - Tomcat (instructions followed from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html), I have the below error during the deployment.

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: **httpd: no process found**. container_command killhttpd in .ebextensions/https-instance.config failed.

I have created ssl.config (shown below) file which gets picked up during the deployment. But unfortunately the deployment fails with the above error.

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
   Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
   Properties:
   GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
   IpProtocol: tcp
   ToPort: 443
   FromPort: 443
   CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

packages:
 yum:
    mod_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ServerName            www.mydomain.com
        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

        LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
        TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
     </VirtualHost>

 /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
   mode: "000400"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     ....
     -----END CERTIFICATE-----

/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
  mode: "000400"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    ....
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

 container_commands:
   killhttpd:
     command: "killall httpd"
   waitforhttpddeath:
     command: "sleep 3"
```

If the container_command is removed from the file, the deployment completes successfully, but has no effect at the end and https isn't enabled. I have ensured that port 443 is enabled with the security group associated.

Help me understand what is missing in process.

Comment: Looks like `httpd` isn't running when you try to run `killall httpd`. Why are you killing `httpd`?

Comment: As stated in the linked AWS instructions in the user's original paragraph: "The container_commands key stops the httpd service after everything has been configured so that the service uses the new https.conf file and certificate." I have also run into the same issue and have not resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

After snooping around a bit on a deployed server, AWS has configured their worker processes as httpd.worker and not httpd. This can be found in /etc/sysconfig/httpd on the server. Instead of changing killall command in the YAML file, I switched mine to use the following:

```
container_commands:
  killhttpd:
    command: "/sbin/service httpd stop"
  waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

I have not tested the full HTTPS functionality yet but at least this resolved the error specified in this post.